# How to order by field of embedded model in embeds_many mongoid rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have model Transactions that embeds many Events

```
class Transaction
  embeds_many :events
end
```

Model Events has fields `:name` and `:execute_at`

```
class Event
  field :name, type: String
  field :execute_at, type: Date

  embedded_in :transaction, inverse_of: :events
end
```

What I need to do is to sort Transactions by `execute_at` field of Events with specific name (lets say 'Name1'). Events are unique within each Transaction so there is no issue here.

Example:

```
{
   amount: '123',
  events: [
    {
      name: 'Name1',
      execute_at: someday
    },
    {
      name: 'Name5',
      execute_at: someotherday
    }
}

Transaction2
{
   amount: '124',
  events: [
    {
      name: 'Name1',
      execute_at: someotherday
    },
    {
      name: 'Name11',
      execute_at: somerday
    }
}
```

Basically sort these 2 transactions only taking data for sorting from events with name: 'Name1'

Comment: Use the dot notation: `'events.execute_at' => 1`

Comment: @D.SM While it does some kind of sorting - it doesnt sort based on events with specific names.

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @D.SM added examples to question

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to solve this issue. The way I see it you have 2 options: either you sort the Transaction objects after fetching the data from the DB or use aggregation framework to do the sorting (the problem with using aggregation framework is you will not get Transaction model in the response, you will get a generic BSON::Document instead)

Comment: @UdiCohen sorting in ruby after getting unsorted data from mongo, is exactly how I do it right now. But as number of records grow it might become unusable soon enough

Comment: @ВолодимирКіх agree... you will probably have to switch to aggregation framework

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted_trans = Transaction.where('events.name' => 'Name1').order_by(:'events.execute_at'.asc)
```

or

```
sorted_trans = Transaction.where('events.name' => 'Name1').order_by(:'events.execute_at'.desc)
```

Comment: This solution will not work because the order_by method is not limited to the embedded documents that answer the where clause, the order_by is applied on the entire document that is returned :-\